# $Ker \phi \xrightarrow{\phi'}A \xrightarrow{\phi}B \xrightarrow{\phi''}Coker \phi$ How are the maps $\phi'$ and $\phi''$ defined?

Tags: category-theory

Consider  in some category

$Ker \phi \xrightarrow{\phi'}A \xrightarrow{\phi}B \xrightarrow{\phi''}Coker \phi$

How are the maps $\phi'$ and $\phi''$ defined? Does it depend on the category?  I mean what are $\phi'(x)=?$ and $\phi''(x) =?$
I am guessing the first one is the inclusion map?

I am hoping to check knowing this that $\phi\circ \phi'=0$ and $\phi''\circ\phi=0$
which brings me to ask also how to check the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not talking about category theory, but rather about abelian groups, or rings, or similar, the definition of these maps are canonical: $\phi'$ is the inclusion map, and $\phi''$ is the quotient map, end of story.

In category theory, however, these maps aren't defined that way at all:

> Given a morphism $\phi: A\to B$, a kernel of $\phi$ is an object $\ker \phi$ together with a morphism $\phi':\ker\phi\to A$ such that $\phi\circ\phi'$ is the zero morphism, required to fulfill the following: For any other object $C$ and morphism $\varphi:C\to A$ such that $\phi\circ\varphi$ is the zero morphism, there is a unique morphism $\varphi':C\to \ker \phi$ such that $\varphi = \phi'\circ\varphi'$

Note that in true category fashion, there are no details whatsoever about what $\ker \phi$ and $\phi'$ actually are. Which is to say, any object that is isomorphic to $\ker \phi$ is also a kernel, with its own version of $\phi'$.

To give an example, in group theory, with the map $\phi = \Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z_2$ given by reduction modulo 2, the kernel is $2\Bbb Z$, with $\phi'$ given by inclusion, and it can't be anything else. But in category theory, $\Bbb Z$, with $\phi'$ given by multiplication by $2$ is just as valid a kernel. And I'm sure you can come up with a bunch more examples if you think for a few seconds.

A similar argument is true for $\operatorname{coker}\phi$ as well, of course.

Comment: So if something is A kernel in group theory, it should also be a kernel in the sense of the category-theory definition right? Since it is a generalisation.Same with the cokernel. About the cokernel, why is $\phi''\circ\phi(x) =0$?

Comment: @darkside Indeed, **the** group theoretic (or ring theoretic, or whatever) kernel is **a** category theoretic kernel. That's the entire point of the definition, and it's the reason the category theoretic construction here has even "earned" the name "kernel" in the first place. As for the cokernel, that's the quotient group $B/\operatorname{Im}\phi$ (or in category theory, a generalisation of that quotient). So $\phi''\circ\phi$ is pretty directly baked into the definition.

Comment: (Alternately, since we have a category theoretic definition of kernel, we obtain the category theoretic definition of cokernel by reversing the direction of every morphism. And that means that instead of $\phi\circ \phi'=0$ in the kernel, we get $\phi''\circ\phi=0$.

Comment: Sorry it is just that managing quotient is always confusing to me so I wanted to check this small example. So if x is an integer we have $\phi (x) =x mod 2$ (not sure if there is a better way to denote this) and then the projection into the quotient should sent this to its class $\phi''(\phi(x) ) =[x mod2] $... Why is this 0?

Comment: @darkside it is $0$ because you are taking the quotient by the image of $\phi$

Comment: @darkside The (group-theoretic) definition of cokernel is basically that $\phi''\circ\phi=0$, together with $\phi''(x)=0\implies$ (there is a $y\in A$ such that $x=\phi(y)$). That's exactly what the quotient construction does.